# How to write Jest unit test for node controller

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to unit test and tried to write test for my controller (ProgramsController).According to my understanding i want to mock my `programService` and it return values.
I would really appreciate some one can fix this.then i can get idea and write jest test for other services.

I tried as below and got error

**ProgramsController.js**

```
class ProgramsController {
    constructor() {
        this.programService = new ProgramService();
    }
    async subscribe(req, res) {
        const { userId, uuid, msisdn, body: { programId } } = req;
        const data = { userId, programId, msisdn, uuid }

        const subscribe = await this.programService.subscribeUser(data);
        res.send({
            status: true,
            message: constant.MSG.SUCCESS,
            friendly_message: constant.MSG.SUCCESS,
            data: subscribe
        }
    }
}
module.exports = ProgramsController;
```

**ProgramService.js**

```
class ProgramService {

    constructor() {
        this.subscriber = new Subscriber();
        this.subsciberProgram = new SubsciberProgram()
    }

    async subscribeUser(data) {
        try {
            const { msisdn, userId, programId, uuid } = data;
                ...

            return subscribedData;

        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
module.exports = ProgramService;
```

test.spec.js

```
const ProgramsService = require('../src/services/program/programService')
const ProgramsController = require('../src/controllers/programs/programsController')
const programController = new ProgramsController()
const programsService = new ProgramsService()


describe("Check method \'subscribe\' ", () => {
    it('should retrieve success', async () => {

        const serviceRecord = { userId: 1, programId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };

        jest.spyOn(programsService, 'subscribeUser').mockResolvedValueOnce(serviceRecord);

        const mReq = { body: { programId: 1 }, userId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };
        const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };


        await programController.subscribe(mReq, mRes);

        expect(programsService.subscribeUser).toBeCalledWith(serviceRecord);
        expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(200);

        expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ program_id: 1, amount: 5, no_of_questions: 10 });
    });
});
```

[image: Jest test]

**------- *** Update (for @tmhao2005) *** ---------**

**test.spec.js**

```
const ProgramsController = require('../src/controllers/programs/programsController')

const serviceRecord = { userId: 1, programId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };

// Mock subscribe user fn
const mockSubscribeUser = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(serviceRecord);

// Mock the service
class MockService {
  subscribeUser = mockSubscribeUser;
}

// Apply the mock before the test run
jest.mock('../src/services/program/programService', () => MockService)

describe("Check method \'subscribe\' ", () => {
  it('should retrieve success', async () => {
    const mReq = { body: { programId: 1 }, userId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };

    const programController = new ProgramsController()
    await programController.subscribe(mReq, mRes);

    expect(mockSubscribeUser).toBeCalledWith(serviceRecord);
    expect(mRes.status).toBeaCalledWith(200);

    expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ program_id: 1, amount: 5, no_of_questions: 10 });
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the instance of `ProgramsService` in your test and your actual code are different. In this case, you just simply mock entire module `ProgramsService` by using `jest.mock` method. Here is the snippet of the idea:

```js
const ProgramsController = require('../src/controllers/programs/programsController')
const serviceRecord = { userId: 1, programId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };

// Mock subscribe user fn
const mockSubscribeUser = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(serviceRecord);

// Apply the mock before the test run
jest.mock('../src/services/program/programService', () => class MockService {
  subscribeUser = mockSubscribeUser;
})

describe("Check method \'subscribe\' ", () => {
  it('should retrieve success', async () => {
    const mReq = { body: { programId: 1 }, userId: 1, msisdn: '56768382967', uuid: '46651a19-3ef1-4149-818e-9bd8a5f359ef' };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };

    const programController = new ProgramsController()
    await programController.subscribe(mReq, mRes);

    expect(mockSubscribeUser).toBeCalledWith(serviceRecord);
    expect(mRes.status).toBeaCalledWith(200);

    expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ program_id: 1, amount: 5, no_of_questions: 10 });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.but i got this error ` ReferenceError: MockService is not defined
 jest.mock('../src/services/program/programService', () => MockService)
`

Comment: Can you take a screenshot fo the test & the error you have seen? It's strange since the `MockService` is defined there

Comment: Are you missing to copy the mocked things `// Mock the service
class MockService {
  subscribeUser = mockSubscribeUser;
}` ?

Comment: No.its there.i have copied your entire answer and placed in to my test.js file

Comment: Hmm. Can you update your entire test file again which reflects on my changes?

Comment: i have updated my question.now test.js file only have your code.but still showing same error

Comment: Okay I'm not sure is there something special with your case. But I just updated to mock result as an inline class though. Try it then.

Comment: @Tje123 how it goes now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221616/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-tje123).